# Why there are 3 different ports for the .net core 2.1 SPA?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm learning dotnet core 2.1 SPA, and when I run the `donet core 2.1 SPA  Angular` with `dotnet run`, I noticed that there are 3 differnt ports:

1. `https:localhost:5001`
2. `http:localhost:5000`
3. `http:localhost:34941`

When I use the second url, it just automatically redirect to the first url, and I got security error. 
For the 3rd url, it works. I think because it's for the client, where 1st and 2nd url would be used for APIs calls with authentications?
What would happen in a live environment?

[image: Result from running <code>dotnet run</code>]

The configuration in Program.cs file

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

Comment: which source code are you running? you may want to chek the program.cs file. also, paste `CreateWebHostBuilder` function code here

Comment: @NevilleNazerane I just updated my question.

Answer (score 11):

#### 5000 and 5001: Kestrel HTTP and HTTPS Defaults

5000 is for HTTP and 5001 is for HTTPS. Those are [defaults in the ASP.NET Core Kestrel Server](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dfaf37cbba684a9913b79ec68fdf5ad18378c170/src/Kestrel.Core/Internal/Infrastructure/Constants.cs). 5000 redirects to 5001 because of `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` in your Startup class.

#### 34941: Any available port for the NG Live Development Server

This is an arbitrary, available port that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices` uses to start the NG Live Development Server. The `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")` method in your Startup class calls the the `start` script from your `package.json` file like this:

```
ng serve --extract-css "--port" "50415"`
```

The port that it passes is any currently [available port](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/c8b337ebaa67c888901cbed4b3fd574a9113df15/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions/AngularCli/AngularCliMiddleware.cs#L69-L74) that the `SpaServices` find.

#### See also

- https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices
- https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer

Comment: Thanks for the great explentation. how can we tell SpaServices not to look for available port BUT set a default port ? or how we tell to visual studio to automatically open the web browser in the found port ?

Comment: @StavBodik In case you still need an answer: You can simply set it in your ng serve, but add "-port 4200 &REM" after it.  &REM is a DOS "command", that treats everything after it as a comment. So you would end up with something like "ng serve -port 4200 &REM"

Comment: @MortenMoulder Thanks for that explanation! This has been a frustrating issue. Weird that you have to hack things like that just to set a port manually.